# How to fix error returned by __soapCall?

Tags: php, service

`$param['websiteConfigID'] = 729872;
$param['numberOfRecords'] = 10;
$param['numberOfRecords'] = 10;
$client = new SoapClient(WSDL);

$result = $client->__soapCall('GetTicketsStringInputs', array('parameters' => $param));`

`$result` holding this error message....

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: 
[Client] Function ("GetTicketsStringInputs") is not a valid method for this service in /home/fmticket/public_html/inc/genericLib.php:279 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/fmticket/public_html/inc/genericLib.php(279): SoapClient->__soapCall('GetTicketsStrin...', Array) 
#1 /home/fmticket/public_html/resultsTicket.php(12): getTickets(Array) 
#2 {main} thrown in /home/fmticket/public_html/inc/genericLib.php on line 279
```

how to resolve it?? plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is calling the remote `GetTicketsStringInputs` function :

```
$client->__soapCall('GetTicketsStringInputs', ...
```

The Fatal error you get indicates :

```
Function ("GetTicketsStringInputs") is not a valid method for this service
```

It seems pretty clear : the method you're trying to call doesn't exist, it is not provided by the remote web-service.

So, to fix that Fatal Error, you have to stop calling that function ;-)

You should check the WSDL of your webservice : does it really export such a method ?

Comment: Thank you very much...! what a suggestion...! I have recovered.

Comment: There was a problem in function name. The correct function name was.. GetTickets, Thanks martin...!